# Oracle Apex When Sub region overflow Horizontal Scroll Bar add in Parent Region

Tags: oracle-apex

Need a solution when child region classic report overflow Parent region horizontal Scroll bar add.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to add a horizontal scrollbar into the Classic report region. If that's so, two options I know (adjust values so that they fit your report; these are just examples):

Put this into **region header**:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow: auto">
```

**Region footer**:

```
</div>
```

---

Another option: put this into the **HTML header**:

```
<style type="text/css">
  <!--
    div.scroll 
    {
      height: 300px;
      width: 500px;
      overflow: auto;
      border: 1px solid #666;
      background-color: #CCC;
      padding: 8px;
    }
 -->
</style>
```

**Region header**:

```
<div class="scroll">
```

**Region footer**:

```
</div>
```